# Как ставить пустоту или 0 в переменную, если нет элемента?

Tags: javascript

У меня скрипт цепляет с сайта данные вставленные в data в некоторых случаях data нет, но в скрипте есть код который пытается найти его, но не находит и ставит null мне нужно или 0 или пустоту записывать в переменную, как это сделать?

```
status_deals = document.getElementById(''+a+'').getAttribute('data-status-deals'); //здесь нужен 0

name_deals = document.getElementById(''+a+'').getAttribute('data-name-deals'); // здесь нужна пустота
```

или на сервере проверку сделать на это

```
$status_deals = isset($_GET['status_deals']) ? (int) $_GET['status_deals'] : 0; // тут если приходит null не ставится 0, а нужно если нет или null, то 0

$name_deals = checkrequest(urldecode($_GET['name_deals'])); // тут лучше сохранять пустоту если null вдруг пришол
```

**Как это сделать?**

Comment: Что мешает проверить ответ? Если пришел `null` соответственная реакция.

Comment: @slippyk хочется что-то в одну строку

Comment: Конструкция `? :` вместо `if` пишется в одну строку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
status_deals = document.getElementById(''+a+'').getAttribute('data-status-deals')   || 0; //здесь нужен 0

name_deals = document.getElementById(''+a+'').getAttribute('data-name-deals') || ""; // здесь нужна пустота
```

За PHP не уверен, но вроде как-то так:

```
$status_deals = (isset($_GET['status_deals']) && $_GET['status_deals'])? (int) $_GET['status_deals'] : 0; // тут если приходит null не ставится 0, а нужно если нет или null, то 0

$name_deals = checkrequest(urldecode(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'name_deals', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))); // тут лучше сохранять пустоту если null вдруг пришол
```

Comment: спасибо большое! а на php так же можно решить проблему?

Comment: @AlexanderSizintsev, вся логика в одну строку это конечно круто, но только НЕ через пол года когда вы вернетесь к своему же коду. В php могу ошибаться, но лучше никогда не пользоваться напрямую $_GET а использовать filter_input() функции